# SQL return latest date for each week

Tags: sql, date, distinct, max

I have query that is returning the follwing data:

```
Number  WeekNumber  Date
1111    23          9/11/12 11:01 AM
1111    23          9/11/12 11:58 AM
2222    24          9/17/12 10:14 AM
2222    24          9/18/12 9:52 AM
2222    24          9/19/12 9:46 AM
2222    24          9/20/12 9:42 AM
```

However what I want is to get the latest date for each week, the result should be:

```
Number  WeekNumber  Date
1111    23          9/11/12 11:58 AM
2222    24          9/20/12 9:42 AM
```

What could I use to obtain this. I have tried to use MAX(DATE) but what I am obtaining is the latest date, not the latest date for each week. I have tried with distinct too but I couldn't make it work with the WHERE clause.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There appears to be a 1:1 relationship between Number and WeekNumber which would point to a problem with your data model.

Comment: Hello, actually the data model is fine, the problem is that it happens that for those dates, the numbers has been the same, but the data has been obtained correctly.

Comment: But if there is a possibility that there is an M:N relationship between Number and WeekNumber then that changes the requirement.  The query which @Clev231 proposes won't work in that case.

Comment: People wasted time and energy on answers to the wrong question, because you posted a misleading set of data.  In future please make sure that your questions are clear and accurate.  That means including *representative* sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the apparent 1:1 relationship between `Number` and `WeekNumber` is an artefact of the data you posted and doesn't really apply in your actual data.  If that is the case a straightforward GROUP BY won't provide your answer.

If you are using a flavour of RDBMS which uses analytic functions this will work:

```
select distinct number
       , weeknumber
       , max(date) over (partition by weeknumber) as weekly_max_date
from yourtable;
```

If you don't have analytics you will need to use a correlated sub-query:

```
select distinct t.number
       , t.weeknumber
       , q.weekly_max_date
from yourtable t
     join ( select weeknumber, max(date) as weekly_max_date
            from yourtable
            group by weeknumber) q
     on (q.weeknumber = t.weeknumber)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Number, WeekNumber, MAX([Date])
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Number, WeekNumber
```

You're close with the MAX(Date), however you then need to GROUP BY the other details.

Comment: This fits the sample data the OP posted but won't work with their full data set.